# hold data in session until the user leaves the page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a question about using session, or maybe TempData to store data while working on one page. I store and retrieve data using multiple Ajax requests and I save to session on my controller Action. What I'd like to do is, when user leaves my page, I'd like to clear session variables. How would I do that with session? Or maybe there is some kind of other way to store data only for one http request (I am not sure about this because as I said I have multiple POST as well as GET requests within the page.)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont you make use of `Hiddenfields` in your html to hold that data...

Same as Asp.Net using hiddenfield to store the viewstate data.....

Answer (score 1):

Use Html.HiddenFor(myModel => myModel.SomeField) to do this. You can assign the values to it, and then it will automatically post back the values in to your model which is super handy dandy.

I hope this is helpful!

If you really want to use TempData (which I do on occasion), I have a KeepTempDataAlive(string tempKey) method that looks something like this...

```
if(TempData[tempKey] != null)
{
     TempData.Keep(tempKey);
}
```

That should keep it around for 1 more post back. Just do this as long as you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your intentions.

If you want to do async stuff with Ajax requests, you can store the data in a hidden field or the jQuery .data() on your .success event. Then when everything is done, use jQuery to populate what you need done.

If you want a true session variable (across multiple pages), then the best way to do that is an AJAX process on window.close to clear out session. Although that's limited to users who have javascript enabled. I don't think there's a foolproof way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem utilizing jQuery and an ajax request that runs when the page unloads.

In your javascript:

```
$(window).unload(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: applicationPath + "/api/ExampleApiController/ExampleWebMethod",
    async: false,
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
      "someVariable": anythingYouWantToPassIfAny,
      "otherVariable": anythingElseYouWantToPass,
    }
  });
});
```

Note: You need to set async: false or else the page will unload before it has a chance to run the ajax request. For the type you can use either a GET or POST, whatever your preference is and what you all want to do with the request.

Then in your api controller:

```
public class ExampleApiController
{
  [HttpGet]
  public void ExampleWebMethod(string someVariable, string otherVariable)
  {
     HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove("sessionVariableA");
     HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove("sessionVariableB");
     ...
  }
}
```

You can also add code to check the return if you want to see if it was successful or not, but in my case I just wanted a quick thing to run and didn't really want it to return anything and it wasn't a big deal if it failed so I just send the request off and unload. I know this question is old, but hopefully it will help someone else.

Note: The problem with this solution is that if the user refreshes the page it will still call the unload event and drop all your session variables.